# Tracking Pixels and Page Load Time for GTMetrix

Tags: javascript

We have a client that wants oodles of tracking pixels - but also doesn't want page load times / site grade affected as seen in gtmetrix.com. I personally am at a loss for how to accomplish this, as it takes the site percentage from a 93% to a 60% when tracking pixels are added. It also doubles the "fully loaded" page time from 2 seconds to 4.5 seconds.

How are people handling this?

Answer (score 0):

I feel your pain, just sayin #GDPR.... An option would be to load them via Google Tag Manager and fire the tag manager after the site is fully rendered.

edit: 
forget to mention, this saved us ~2sec in loading and tracking works great.